# Get the combined row count by month from 3 tables

Tags: postgresql, join, count, union

Using Postgres 10+, I have three tables with similar structures, where I'm trying to get a count of rows grouped by months. I have a functional query working for two tables, as below:

```
CREATE TABLE classroom_observations (id SERIAL, created_at TIMESTAMPTZ);
CREATE TABLE training_modules       (id SERIAL, created_at TIMESTAMPTZ);
CREATE TABLE teachers_workshops     (id SERIAL, created_at TIMESTAMPTZ);

INSERT INTO classroom_observations VALUES
 (1, '2019-04-20 10:36:06+02')
,(2, '2019-05-22 15:22:33+02')
,(3, '2019-05-23 15:22:33+02')
,(4, '2019-05-24 15:22:33+02');
INSERT INTO training_modules VALUES
 (1, '2019-03-20 10:36:06+02')
,(2, '2019-04-22 15:22:33+02')
,(3, '2019-04-23 15:22:33+02')
,(4, '2019-05-24 15:22:33+02');
INSERT INTO teachers_workshops VALUES
 (1, '2019-03-20 10:36:06+02');
```

```
SELECT * FROM
  (
      SELECT to_char(co.created_at, 'YYYY-MM') AS month
           , COUNT(co.id) AS co_count
           , COUNT(tm.id) AS tm_count
        FROM classroom_observations co
       LEFT JOIN training_modules tm
          ON to_char(co.created_at, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(tm.created_at, 'YYYY-MM')
       GROUP BY to_char(co.created_at, 'YYYY-MM'), to_char(tm.created_at, 'YYYY-MM')
      UNION
      SELECT to_char(tm.created_at, 'YYYY-MM') AS month
           , COUNT(co.id) AS co_count
           , COUNT(tm.id) AS tm_count
           FROM classroom_observations co
           RIGHT JOIN training_modules tm
          ON to_char(co.created_at, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(tm.created_at, 'YYYY-MM')
       GROUP BY to_char(co.created_at, 'YYYY-MM'), to_char(tm.created_at, 'YYYY-MM')
      ) tbl
  ORDER BY Month;
```

This produces the expected result:

```
  month  | co_count | tm_count 
---------+----------+----------
 2019-03 |        0 |        1
 2019-04 |        1 |        2 
 2019-05 |        3 |        1
```

When I try to add the third table `teachers_workshops`, with count a count of `tw.id` as `tw_count`, I get the wrong result:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (
      SELECT to_char(co.created_at, 'YYYY-MM') AS month
           , COUNT(co.id) AS co_count
           , COUNT(tm.id) AS tm_count
           , COUNT(tw.id) AS tw_count
        FROM classroom_observations co
       LEFT JOIN training_modules tm
          ON to_char(co.created_at, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(tm.created_at, 'YYYY-MM')
       LEFT JOIN teachers_workshops tw
          ON to_char(co.created_at, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(tw.created_at, 'YYYY-MM')
       GROUP BY to_char(co.created_at, 'YYYY-MM'), to_char(tm.created_at, 'YYYY-MM') , to_char(tw.created_at, 'YYYY-MM')
      UNION
      SELECT to_char(tm.created_at, 'YYYY-MM') AS month
           , COUNT(co.id) AS co_count
           , COUNT(tm.id) AS tm_count
           , COUNT(tw.id) AS tw_count
           FROM classroom_observations co
           RIGHT JOIN training_modules tm
          ON to_char(co.created_at, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(tm.created_at, 'YYYY-MM')
           RIGHT JOIN teachers_workshops tw
          ON to_char(co.created_at, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(tw.created_at, 'YYYY-MM')
       GROUP BY to_char(co.created_at, 'YYYY-MM'), to_char(tm.created_at, 'YYYY-MM'), to_char(tw.created_at, 'YYYY-MM')
      UNION
      SELECT to_char(tm.created_at, 'YYYY-MM') AS month
           , COUNT(co.id) AS co_count
           , COUNT(tm.id) AS tm_count
           , COUNT(tw.id) AS tw_count
           FROM classroom_observations co
           RIGHT JOIN training_modules tm
          ON to_char(co.created_at, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(tm.created_at, 'YYYY-MM')
           RIGHT JOIN teachers_workshops tw
          ON to_char(co.created_at, 'YYYY-MM') = to_char(tw.created_at, 'YYYY-MM')
       GROUP BY to_char(co.created_at, 'YYYY-MM'), to_char(tm.created_at, 'YYYY-MM'), to_char(tw.created_at, 'YYYY-MM')
      ) tbl
  ORDER BY Month;
```

Bad Result:

```
  month  | co_count | tm_count | tw_count 
---------+----------+----------+----------
 2019-04 |        1 |        0 |        0
 2019-05 |        6 |        6 |        6
```

There should only be 1 record for `tw_count`, and there should be another month included `2019-03`. I'm clearly not wrapping my head around this properly, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Add some sample data as insert statements (create table statements as well), together with the expected result.

Comment: If you are just `trying to get a count of rows grouped by months`, then why the `LEFT` and `RIGHT JOIN`. That's doing something else, possibly multiplying row counts. And why eliminate duplicates with `UNION` instead of `UNION ALL`? Please explain what you are actually counting / doing in the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to get a count of rows grouped by months

The queries you show do something potentially quite different. To achieve your declared objective:

```
SELECT to_char(mon, 'YYYY-MM') AS month
     , COALESCE(co.ct, 0) AS co_count
     , COALESCE(tm.ct, 0) AS tm_count
     , COALESCE(tw.ct, 0) AS tw_count
FROM  (
   SELECT date_trunc('month', created_at) AS mon, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   classroom_observations
   GROUP  BY mon
   ) co
FULL JOIN (
   SELECT date_trunc('month', created_at) AS mon, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   training_modules
   GROUP  BY mon
   ) tm USING (mon)
FULL JOIN (
   SELECT date_trunc('month', created_at) AS mon, count(*) AS ct
   FROM   teachers_workshops
   GROUP  BY mon
   ) tw USING (mon)
ORDER  BY mon;
```

Result:

```
  month  | co_count | tm_count | tw_count 
---------+----------+----------+----------
 2019-03 |        0 |        1 |        1
 2019-04 |        1 |        2 |        0
 2019-05 |        3 |        1 |        0
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=68e84cd308fa84639f074be32484e913)*

- [`FULL [OUTER] JOIN`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#id-1.5.6.6.5.6.2) keeps all rows, even without match on the other side.
- Results in `NULL` values where no rows are found - which I replace with `0` using [`COALESCE`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-COALESCE-NVL-IFNULL) as an optional addition.
- [`date_trunc()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) is faster and more reliable than [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE). Aggregate and join on the truncated timestamp and only format once with `to_char()` in the outer `SELECT`.

Comment: Thanks. I think I was struggling with the problem for so long that I managed to massively overcomplicate things. I appreciate the help, and the much simpler solution.